# What do these words and sentences mean?

Tags: idioms, slang, cinema, meaning

I'm translating an episode of a TV series called "Sons of Anarchy". In a scene (where business partners have a meeting):

> A: "Quinn showed us some Red Woody rough cuts. Business is good."
>
> B: Beats cranking a wrench, huh?

I want to ask what the word "rough cuts" here means? And what does the sentence "Beats cranking a wrench" mean?

Comment: This really belongs in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A:  The bikers made porn videos to support their club.  The initial filmings of such were the **rough cuts** awaiting editing and their business was named *Red Woody*, pun intended.

B: **beats cranking a wrench** = beats working (cranking say, a plumber's wrench) for a living!

Comment: I am afraid you have confused *rough cut* with *dailies* (or *rushes*).

Answer (score 0):

In filmmaking, ***rough cut*** is an intermediate stage of the editing process (after *initial assembly* and before *final cut*).

> The rough cut is the first stage in which the film begins to resemble
>   its final product. The term originates from the early days of
>   filmmaking when film stock was physically cut and reassembled, but is
>   still used to describe projects that are recorded and edited
>   digitally.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_cut
>
> The rough cut is the first true edit and is the stage in which you
>   start to display your craft as more than a technical exercise. At this
>   stage, it is no longer about solely discovering and organizing
>   footage, it’s about storytelling and crafting a message, using the
>   footage from production as a foundation to achieve the director’s
>   vision.
>   https://www.videomaker.com/article/c3/17887-stages-of-editing